# Clean obj directory in Visual Web Developer Express 2008

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I am using the following post-build event line to delete my project obj/ directory in VS WebDev 2008:

rmdir $(ProjectDir)obj /s /q

This seems to delte the *files* but leaves an empty Debug/Release directory in there, and either complains that "directory is not empty", or it silently fails to delete obj and obj/Debug. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: is there a reason you need to delete the obj directory after every build?

Answer (score 0):

obj folder is by design the folder for garbage, so why you would like to manually clean it up every time? Leave it there is a common thing.

To clean up your folders, you should execute Clean target instead of Build or Rebuild.

Comment: I'd like to keep obj files separate from my source files so they doesn't get in the way of version control.

Comment: I am not sure what version control software you use, but most of them allows you to ignore such obj folders.